# PHP: Set current Joomla username as variable

Tags: php, variables, joomla, joomla3.0

how can I set in a php-script the username of the user, that is logged in at the moment, as a variable?
I know, how I can get and display the current username, but how can I set this as a variable?

This is the code, which I want to set as a variable:

```
<?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $user->username;
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know, how I can get and display the current username. But how can I set this as a variable?

Comment: I know how I can set a variable in PHP

Comment: So you know how to get the Joomla username, you know how to set a variable, but you do not know how to *"set the current Joomla username as variable"*? Please rephrase your question, because it seems like it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already almost doing it.

```
<?php
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $username = $user->username;
?>
```

Though, `$user->username` is already containing this information, so I think that is why everyone is confused.

Comment: Perfect, that's the solution! Another problem was in the MySQL Query because I insert there the variable $username wrong. Thanks for your help!